# find the value of $t$ if any at which the tangential component of acceleration is equal to the normal component

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

> A point on a rifle bullet travels according to the position function $$r(t) = \langle5t^2,\cos(t^2), \sin(t^2)\rangle$$
>   Find the value of $t$ if any at which the tangential component of acceleration is equal to the normal component.

I have found Velocity , Acceleration and the Normal and Tangential Components of acceleration it is a ton of work to get to this point so not expecting anyone to actually go through this just a hint on what to do next.

Comment: I'm assuming you are saying that you've found the parametric functions for the normal and tangential acceleration _vectors_.  It sounds like they want you to find the parameter value at which the _magnitudes_ are equal.  Since the magnitudes are always positive or zero, you can just compare the squares of the magnitudes, which lets you dispose of radicals...

Comment: Yes, i found the normal and tangential parametric functions for the acceleration vector. What reason would i have to square each function? I knew i had to set them equal to each other but im not quite following the logic here. Magnitudes of the Tang. and Norm components represent what exactly?

Comment: Not squaring the functions, but rather the magnitudes; but it's really the same as just comparing the arguments of the radicals, as **user40615**'s answer illustrates.  (The magnitudes are the speeds along the tangent and the normal to the curve at each point.)

Comment: I see, thank you very much man i appreciate you taking the time to help : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$v=r'(t)=\bigg \langle 10t, -2t\sin(t^2), 2t\cos (t^2)\bigg\rangle\Rightarrow |v|=\sqrt{104}t$, and $a_T=\frac{d|v|}{dt}=\sqrt{104}.$

$a=r''(t)=\bigg\langle 10, -2\sin(t^2)-4t^2\cos(t^2), 2\cos(t^2)-4t^2\sin(t^2)\bigg\rangle\Rightarrow |a|= \sqrt{16t^4+100t^2+4}$.

$\Rightarrow a_N= \sqrt{|a|^2-a^2_T}=\sqrt{16t^4+100t^2-100}$. Thus, $a_T=a_N\Rightarrow 4t^4+25t^2-51=0\Rightarrow t^2= \frac{-25+\sqrt{1441}}{8}\Rightarrow t\approx 1,27.$

Comment: Thanks a lot i appreciate the help although i did it the long way hahaha this way is much , much simpler thanks again man i appreciate it. This helped me verify my answer.

Comment: I noticed you have a 100t^2 in your final answer for mag. |a| which i do believe is incorrect. It should just be 100 ?